# export data from sql server 2000 to excel

Tags: excel, sql-server-2000

Is it any method or way to export or transfer the data from sql server 2000 to excel sheet ?

Comment: You can use OPENROWSET http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1202

Comment: From which end? You say 'export', but 'import' works quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010617/query-sql-from-excel-2007-and-return-several-values/5011166#5011166

Comment: @Remou, I want to export Or transfer data by inbuilt any tool in sql server 2000. Or import data in excel sheet from sql server 2000 by any tool exist in MS Excel. I must avoid programming for that for now.

Comment: In that case http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx

Comment: i think it is about office 2010. is there remedy for office 2003 or 2007

Comment: The comment at the top refers to a link to 2010, the article itself is about earlier versions, as far as I know. I can certainly get external data with my 2000 version of Excel.

Answer (score 3):

to create an EXCEL file in advance and want to export data to it, use

```
EXEC sp_makewebtask 
@outputfile = 'd:\testing.xls', 
@query = 'Select * from Database_name..SQLServerTable', 
@colheaders =1, 
@FixedFont=0,@lastupdated=0,@resultstitle='Testing details'
```

(Now you can find the file with data in tabular format)